# Adressing specific itemlist values in Checkboxlists

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Chechboxlist Networks]

I'm working with a checkboxlist for the first time ever and I'm a bit perplexed at how to go about addressing dealing with individual values of the check boxes on the list. Above is a rendering of the one of the lists that I am working with and below is the ASP.NET code driving it along with the what I 'thought' should be about the right approach to populate this list with check boxes based on the data in the table being referenced which as bit values with 1's flagged for all these items (1 column for each item).  I've seen 'foreach' references but I would much prefer specific calling by item list name references rather than make an assumption on a long list of checkboxes that I have proper correlation.

Of course the problem here is that Items doesn't like being used like a method.

**** THE ASP.NET code ***

```
  <%-- NetworkChklist for Networks --%>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="NetworkChklist" runat="server" BackColor="DeepSkyBlue" Font-Size="X-Small">
    <asp:ListItem>&nbsp;IDS / IPS</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>&nbsp;Network</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>&nbsp;Firewall</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

***CODE BEHIND FAILURE ****

```
NetworkChklist.Items("IDS / IPS").Value = DocumentsVal.IDS_IPS.Value;
NetworkChklist.Items("Network").Value = DocumentsVal.Network.Value;
NetworkChklist.Items("Firewall").Value = DocumentsVal.Firewall.Value;e here
```

Any help would be appreciated I have 3 of these that are all larger to deal with I can modify the database if I need to but would rather not.

Appreciate it!
Ken...

Comment: So `DocumentsVal.IDS_IPS.Value` is a bit value coming from the dB? You maybe looking for `.Checked` instead of `.Value`

Comment: Also `NetworkChklist.Items` might only except an array index position and not the text value of the item (i.e. `NetworkChklist.Items(0)`). I think there is a `NetworkChklist.FindItemByText("Value")` that you can use

Comment: Changing the Text values to index  values didn't help matters and neither did altering .values to .checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Selected` property to check/uncheck each item. As for referring to an item, it can be done by index:

```
NetworkChklist.Items[0].Selected = DocumentsVal.IDS_IPS.Value;
NetworkChklist.Items[1].Selected = DocumentsVal.Network.Value;
NetworkChklist.Items[2].Selected = DocumentsVal.Firewall.Value;
```

or it can be done by value. Once the `Value` property of each item is set in markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="NetworkChklist" runat="server" BackColor="DeepSkyBlue" Font-Size="X-Small">
    <asp:ListItem Value="IDS_IPS" Text="&nbsp;IDS / IPS" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Network" Text="&nbsp;Network" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Firewall" Text="&nbsp;Firewall" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

you can use it in code-behind:

```
NetworkChklist.Items.FindByValue("IDS_IPS").Selected = DocumentsVal.IDS_IPS.Value;
NetworkChklist.Items.FindByValue("Network").Selected = DocumentsVal.Network.Value;
NetworkChklist.Items.FindByValue("Firewall").Selected = DocumentsVal.Firewall.Value;
```

You could use `FindByText` instead of `FindByValue` but you would have to replace `&nbsp;` by an unbreakable space (`\u00A0`). It doesn't look very good, in my opinion:

```
NetworkChklist.Items.FindByText("\u00A0Firewall").Selected = DocumentsVal.Firewall.Value;
```

Note: As mentioned by zgood, I assumed that `DocumentsVal.(...).Value` are boolean values.

Comment: Using the *** NetworkChklist.Items.FindByValue("Firewall").Selected = DocumentsVal.Firewall.value; *** approach was successful in eliminating the redlines but was throwing NULL check errors even though the database was populated on the column in question (Firewall). Currently I have the database configured to house these values as Bit so they are True or False. I verified that they were true for the columns I was testing on before running this but the Null check errors persist.

Comment: Are these bit fields allowed to be NULL in the database? I understand from your comment that `DocumentsVal.Firewall.Value` is not true/false but has some `null` or `DBNull` value.

Comment: I did have them set to allow null so I changed that in hopes that it might change things.. it did! it cause the .value to redline but I found that I could remove the .value from the line leave it to read = DocumentsVal.Firewall and Intellisense was happy.  Ran it and debug stopped me saying "Look son you gotta do a null check here before you look at this data!"... so I put in a check for null on DocumentsVal.Firewall ahead of this and what did I get?  I got "Look Son! Don't be checkin for null on Bool cuz Bool is either true or false it ante gonna be null!."  Fun Microsoft!